# How can I test an Activity that depends on another one being created?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I'm new on Unit Testing.

I want to test an activity called Login. I'm extending `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Login>` from the out-of-the-box api to develop the testing class.
The problem is that the Login Activity is started after another Activity,
which in turn, is started by a splash screen Activity.

The activity started in the middle starts some services and initialize some objects needed for the Login Activity I'm trying to test to work properly, so I need to have it created first.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just start your activity from a test case?  Why not create a stub test activity that starts your login activity?

Comment: @Deev I guess that's the point. I will try that approach. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html) provides functional testing of a single Activity. You need a different approach to test more than one Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could broadcast an `Intent` after everything you need has been initialized, then create a `BraodcastRecevier` to start the login process.

Alternatively, you could use message/handler communication to handle when a new activity is launched.

Comment: But It seems that the testing framework itself, starts the Login activity directly, ignoring the activity chain that leads to it. So I dont have what I need initialized.